# "assets" getting prefixed on a link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a link_to in a partial that generates a different URL when the page is accessed as the root then if it is accessed using controller/index.  When accessed as the root, the URL the link_to generates has "assets" prefixed to it, which doesn't work.

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Rails 3.2.1 
Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from the Rails IRC channel, I found the problem.  I was not using the helper paths in the link.  In case it will help someone else, here is what I did to fix it;

not working when at the root;

<%= link_to 'Gifts detail', :controller => 'gifts', :action => 'index'%>

working anytime;

<%= link_to 'Gifts detail', gifts_path%>

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but I want to direct the link to a unique controller action. Any idea what I can do?

Comment: Can you set up a route like match ''/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'' then in your link something like '<%= link_to 'Contacts', '/contact'%>'  This is just off the top of my head and I am still trying to get my brain around this stuff.

Comment: I'm using the rails resources in the config/routes.rb file. I dont want to mess with the routing unless I really have to.